# How to access elements of a String array from main()

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am having difficulty retrieving a value from a string array.

I need to have it output the name of the day of the week.. i.e. Sunday for the number 0. I have the code perfect for outputting the numbers, but I can't get it to pull from my array of day names.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FutureDateJava {
    String[] dayStrings = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
                            "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
                            "Saturday" };

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter today's day: ");
        int today = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter a day in the future ");
        int future = input.nextInt();

        int futureDay = (today + future) % 7;

        System.out.print("Today is " + today + 
            " and the future day is " + futureDay);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually access the array:

```
System.out.print("Today is " + dayStrings [today % 7] + " and the future day is " + dayStrings [futureDay]);
```

The `%7` is to make sure that a day (eg 10) doesn't cause an out of bounds exception. However, this isn't exactly optimal, it assumes that Monday is day 0, but the idea is there.

Comment: No need to use `futureDay % 7` again.

Comment: I'm glad to know I was sort of close.  I did try the code and when I use the textpad compiler it says error a non-static variable dayStrings cannot be referenced from a static context and then shows the System.out.print

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, make dayStrings `static`. If the array isn't gonna change, so also consider making it `final`,